# Using requestAnimationFrame inside requestIdleCallback

Tags: javascript, dom, requestanimationframe, requestidlecallback

If I animate changes in the DOM from JS (e.g. changing the value of a node's textContent from 1 to 500), would it be better to use `requestAnimationFrame` or `requestAnimationFrame` within a `requestIdleCallback`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate some code, then use only `requestAnimationFrame`, if you want to perform an action only when the browser has nothing else to do anymore, then use `requestIdleCallback`.

To simplify things, let's consider that both `requestAnimationFrame` and `requestIdleCallback` are `setTimeout` calls, with variables timeout arguments.

`requestAnimationFrame` would then be `setTimeout(fn, time_until_next_screen_refresh)`. `fn` will be called right before the page is painted to the screen. This is currently the best timer we have to make animations since it ensures we'll only do the visual modifications only once per actual frame, at the speed of what the monitor is able to render, thus at every frame, if our code is fast enough.

`requestIdleCallback` would be `setTimeout(fn, time_until_idle)`. `fn` will be called as soon as the browser has nothing more to do. This can be right away, or in a few event loops iterations.

So while both have a similar API, they provide completely different features, and the only viable one for doing an animation is `requestAnimationFrame`, since `requestIdleCallback` has basically no link whatsoever with the rendering.